# The best way to store table data in javascript in case of undo

Tags: jquery, html

I have a html table, in which I'm erasing some `<td>s` and replacing them with `<td>Added!</td>` with ajax when a certain action is taken, like this:

```
 tr.find('.td2').replaceWith('<td>'+my_new_data+'</td>');
```

However, I want to have the option to `undo` the action and I need to put the original `td` data back.

I have a few options I know of:

#### 1) Store the original value in an array

I don't know how to do this, however. The following doesn't work:

```
storedFoodData[id][2] = tr.find('.td2').html();
storedFoodData[id][3] = tr.find('.td3').html();
```

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '6' of undefined

#### 2) Not replace the original TD, just hide() it and append() a new one after it

The problem here is that I'm not sure I can do this, semantically. It should break the html code if I understand it correctly.

Any ideas how to solve this situation?

Comment: do you need redo? is undo triggered on per row basis or just one undo button for whole table? Need multiple undo steps capablitiles? A demo would help if need more than one undo and need redo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use html5 `data-attributes`

Save `html()`  of `td` in data attribute and mark that `td` as lastUpdated `td` by adding a particular class (I am using `active` class). Later on, if someone clicks undo, retrieve the content from data attribute and put that in `html()`

```
  $('.active').removeClass('.active');
    var td = tr.find('.td2');
    td.data('oldData',td.html());
    td.html(my_new_data).addClass('.active');
```

And on click of undo, use this,

```
var active = $('.active');
active.html(active.data('oldData'));
```

Comment: Doesn't the code break if I store ``"`` into the data attribute? Which would result in something like this: ``data-original-value="some_text"text"_here"``

Comment: You could have tried it instead of asking ;) Btw see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/cPywf/)